# Testing GKSession between an ipad and simulator (iOS 6)

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6, ios-simulator, gksession

I am trying to start a GKSession between a simulator and ipad. But i think they are not even connecting because i try to list the clients and servers respectively. Nothing is displayed on both the device and the simulator. I was trying this Ray Wenderlich's tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1 and even the 2nd part of the tutorial. Well I tried downloading their project and tried running it. It does not list the clients and severs so i am assuming that it is not connecting at all. 
And i was thinking maybe its because i am using it on iOS6.0.1? Do you reckon its the version issue?

I am not posting any code here because i was just trying to follow the tutorial above. And ofcourse there are no other error.. they are running perfectly fine, its just that the clients and server is not listed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to answer this, it was because i was trying to run this code in my organization's network environment (the network has restrictions). so when i tried at the home network it did work perfectly fine.

Comment: i was going to post this answer incase some of u all face the same problem.